# How give permission to write on disk or mapped drive

Tags: c#, mvvm, uwp, unauthorizedaccessexcepti, storagefile

i'll just like create a new file on my C disk (and later on my network).

i would like pick a file on a folder with an openFilePicker (that's works) and next with a button copy this file on my desktop for example.

File property :

```
public StorageFile File { get; set; }
```

the openFilePicker code :

```
public async Task GetFileAsync()
        {
            var picker = new FileOpenPicker();
            picker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
            picker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;
            picker.FileTypeFilter.Add("*");

            File = await picker.PickSingleFileAsync();
        }
```

The code to save :

```
public async Task SaveFileAsync()
        {
            try
            {
                StorageFolder test2 = await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(@"C:\Users\bvens\Desktop");

                await File.CopyAsync(test2, File.Name, NameCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
```

But i have an UnauthorizedAccessException when a try to write in "saveFileAsync"
=>

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Accès refusé. (Exception from HRESULT:0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))

thanks

**Edit**
the problem it's that in UWP  the app is in a other thread and so don't have right to write. You need ton ask to your user that your app can go to the target file (like in android)

(We can close this issues)

Comment: I know this link and unfortunaly for me it doesn't explain how can i write on an other disk =/

Answer (score 0):

> When StorageFile.CopyAsync is used to copy a file that is encrypted to a destination that is not encrypted, the call will fail with the following exception: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is denied. (Excep_FromHResult 0x80070005)

I think this is a problem